# Notice: Undefined index: main_profile in include() (line 54

Tags: users

```
global $user;  
$user->uid ;
print_r($user->uid);
print "print out the user value" . $user->uid;

$uid =3;

$account = user_load($user->uid); 

$profile = profile2_load_by_user($account);

$print_first_name =  drupal_render(field_view_field('profile2',$profile['main_profile'], 'field_first_name'));
print $print_first_name;
```

What I have attempted to do is to pass the `$user->uid` to the `user_load` function.
When I pass `$uid = 3` to the `user_load` function it seems to work fine. I am wondering what approach I should try to fix this problem.

error message:

EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type profile2. in entity_extract_ids() (line 7562 of /home/td6/public_html//includes/common.inc).

Comment: This is poorly titled as it seems to be cut off and the error message in the title is different to the one you mention at the end of your post.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistakes is here `main_profile` , profile type always start with **profile_name** . just need change main_profile to **profile_main**

```
global $user;  
$user->uid ;
print_r($user->uid);
print "print out the user value" . $user->uid;

$uid =3;

$account = user_load($user->uid); 
$profile = profile2_load_by_user($account);


$print_first_name =  drupal_render(field_view_field('profile2',$profile['profile_main'], 'field_first_name'));
print $print_first_name;
```

If you want see all your profile type and correct name and it's contents print_r or var_dump `$profile`

```
$profile = profile2_load_by_user($account);
print_r($profile);
```

Comment: profile2 profiles do not always start with profile_, but like you say, the issue is that main_profile is not the name of the profile. Also, drupal_render takes an element by reference so you really should pass in a variable, not a function.  For example, set a variable to the result of field_view_field and then pass the variable into drupal_render().